# Rebus #14 marches on the scene

Tags: rebus

This word cracks me up, because it seems like an oxymoron!

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Infantry?

Also

> seems like an oxymoron since Infantry are definitely not infants!

Comment: @1848:  Right on the mark!

Answer (score 2):

Is it

> infantry ("infant" + "tree")

where

> "oxymoron" is included not because of any true oxymoron present, but
>  because trees emit **oxy**gen and infants, not having attained normal adult intelligence levels (when it comes to performing well on intelligence tests as opposed to, say, learning languages), are in a sense **moron**s.

Comment: Right James! :)